# Conexión SQL con VB6

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb6

Estoy tratando de realizar una conexión a una `BD` de `SQLServer` en `VB6`, pero surge el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es todo el código del módulo:

```
Public Cn As Connection
Public StrCadena As String

Sub Main()
Set Cn = New Connection
    Cn.ConnectionString = "PROVIDER=EJEMPLO;driver={SQL Server};server=EJEMPLO;uid=EJEMPLO;pwd=EJEMPLO;database=EJEMPLO;"
    StrCadena = Cn.ConnectionString
    Cn.Open
End Sub
```

Me dijeron que lo mejor es hacerla por código en un módulo, pero la verdad es que soy bastante nuevo en esto de `VB6` y no se que estaré haciendo mal. ¿Alguna idea o sugerencia?

Comment: Estas seguro que es Connection el objeto? no es ADODB.Connection?

Comment: Incluso aunque ponga ADODB.Connection sigue saliendo el mismo error

Comment: Pero estas agregando esa libreria a las referencias del proyecto?

Comment: Ah, no sabía que requería de una librería. ¿Dónde o como la consigo?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/appendixes/using-ado-with-microsoft-visual-basic?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Vale, muchas muchas gracias. Ehm, ¿podrías añadirlo como respuesta así cierro la pregunta?

Comment: Fijate como se arregla el problema, y escribi vos mismo una respuesta completa. Yo ni tengo un vb6 a mano para fijarme (todo lo que te dije fue de memoria)...

Comment: Vale, vale. Gracias de todas maneras

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solución (gracias a gbianchi):

Pasos a seguir: `Proyecto -> Referencias -> Seleccionar Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.5 Library`

Dejo las capturas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Genial!! recorda pasar en 24 horas y aceptarla!